# Canon PIXMA MG5400 Series driver issues

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing

I run Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit and I have a Canon PIXMA MG5450 printer connected to the PC with cable. I turn it on and it is not recognized automatically, I can't find any drivers official drivers for it.

Is there any unofficial driver that make it work?

Answer (score 0):

On the Swiss Canon support site, I found the [driver source code](http://de.canon.ch/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5440.aspx?type=download&softwaredetailid=tcm:88-994685&os=Linux&language=) for the PIXMA MG5400. Just scroll all the way down and hit "Akzeptieren & Herunderladen" (Accept and Download).

You'll receive a tar.gz archive containing the source code. Extract it and open a terminal in the directory `cnijfilter-source-3.80-1` where you extracted it.

Execute the command `chmod +x scripts/install_deb/install.sh`, then execute `scripts/install_deb/install.sh`

The `make`, `make install` way doesn't work, as the Makefile is corrupted...

This might do it. However, I don't know how old this is and how well it is maintained.

---

EDIT: The other answer points to Canon Singapore, which provides a prepackaged version of the driver for Debian: http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100467602.html?r=s&q=

Download, extract, and run the installer script.

Comment: When I run `install.sh` I get: An error occurred. A necessary package could not be found in the proper location. I think the script is last modified in 2012. Because I see `Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2012`

Comment: Then try `cd scripts/install_deb && ./install.sh`

Comment: Actually I executed the script from the `install_deb` directory.

Comment: Then don't do it, but from the directory with the Makefile in it.

Comment: The Makefile is in the root folder `cnijfilter-source-3.80-1` I get the same error if i try to execute the isntall.sh from there as well. `scripts/install_deb && ./install.sh` or `scripts/install_deb/install.sh`

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: Yes, I downloaded, ran the `install.sh` script, but it failed at a point `cnijfilter-mg5400series depends on libtiff4; however: Package libtiff4 is not installed.` I tried `sudo apt-get install libtiff4` but it is not found in the registry. In system settings -> printers I see Canon MG5400 series with a green tick. I tried a test print, on the printer I saw `Processing... Please wait momentarily` then it disappeared and nothing happend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17359/discussion-between-attila-egyed-and-the-seppi).